# Using - in URLS via mod_rewrite and querying Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem. I am using mod_rewrite to rename my URLS

Everything is working correctly until I reformatted  my URLS so that spaces include - instead of %20.

```
site.com/page.php?country=abc&region=d e f&city=gh i

site.com/abc/d-e-f/gh-i/
```

Currently I am doing this

```
if (isset($_GET['country'])) {$country = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['country']);}
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {$city = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['city']);}
if (isset($_GET['region'])) {$region = str_replace('-', ' ', $_GET['region']);}
```

I then convert back to normal when querying the database for example:

```
str_replace(' ', '-', $_GET['city'])
```

However this has created a problem as some cities use both a space AND a -. **Saint-andre reunion island**.

Initially I thought about running the original SQL query and if 0 results are returned, str_replacing spaces with - before running the query again. However this will only fix it if the city contains ONLY - and 0 space eg **Saint-andre**.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT `name`, FROM `list` WHERE country = '$regionCode[0]' AND admin1 = '$regionCode[1]' AND admin2 = '$regionCode[2]' AND city = '$city' ORDER BY 'moddate'";
```

What is the best way to handle this? Should I use double dashes instead and handle this differently? EG **Saint--andre-reunion-island** or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Often, sites which include a human-readable slug in the URL will *also* include an integer ID.  In that style, you completely ignore the slug on the server side and just query based on the id; that gets you around any issues with duplicate city names.

Comment: Thanks Sam, yes that was another option, I was hoping to avoid using the ID field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decided to go with the double dash option and created a function. I still welcome any other suggestions if there is a better option :)

Code that I am using below.

```
   // URL Database conversion class
function QueryConversion($url) {
$url = str_replace('--', '*', $url);
$url = str_replace('-', ' ', $url);
$url = str_replace('*', '-', $url);
return $url; 
}

// URL conversion class
function URLconversion($url) {
$url = str_replace('-', '--', $url);
$url = str_replace(' ', '-', $url);
return $url;
}

if (isset($_GET['country'])) {$country = QueryConversion($_GET['country']);}
if (isset($_GET['region'])) {$region = QueryConversion($_GET['region']);}
if (isset($_GET['city'])) {$city = QueryConversion($_GET['city']);}
```